# How to solve recurrence in two variables

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, random-walk

How can you solve this simple looking recurrence relation in two variables?

$f(a,b) = 1 + \frac{a f(a+1,b+1) + (x-a)f(a+1,b)}{x}$

The function $f$ is defined for non-negative integer values $a$ and $b$ in the range specified below.

The boundary conditions for the first and second variable are given by fixed integer values $x$ and $y$ which define the problem instance as follows:

$f(x,b) = y-b$

$f(a,y) = 0$

We know $0 < y < x$, $1 \leq a \leq x$ and $0 \leq b \leq y$ and I am trying to compute $f(1,0)$.  Note that $f(1,0)$ should be a function of $x$ and $y$ only.

Comment: To compute $H_1$, you need to find $f(n,0)$. This is straightword. Set $a=n$ and $b=0$ in the formula defining $f(a,b)$. Be careful, call if $H_1(t)$ since the letters $x$ and $y$ are already used.

Comment: @julien What you have done to get f(n,m) = f(n-1,m) + f(n, m-1) from my question.

Comment: Yes, right, I've just read the link you proposed... This does not mean it is fulfilled here, of course. But I think you need to make your question clearer? What kind of recurrence relation are you trying to prove?

Comment: $a,b$ range over what?  Integers?  Positive integers? Real numbers?

Comment: What is $x$? What is $y$?

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(a,b) = 1 + \frac{a f(a+1,b+1) + (x-a)f(a+1,b)}{x},\qquad
f(x,b)=y-b, f(a,y)=0 .
$$
Maybe think of this as a random walk.  We have times $a=1, a=2, \dots$.  We begin at point $0$.  At time $a$, we either move right by one step (with probability $a/x$) or remain where we are (with probability $1-a/x$).  Thus, at time $1$ we are fairly likely to stay put, unlikely to move.  But as time passes, we become more likely to move, less likely to stay put.  Until at time $a=x$ (and after) we are certain to move.  The question is: how long does it take to reach point $y$?  The expected time is our solution $f(1,0)$.